# lapply skipping over the first function argument

Tags: r, lapply, rjson

Is it possible run `lapply` such that the `X` list argument is used as the second argument to `FUN` and the first argument to `FUN` is skipped?

One example is `rjson::fromJSON(json_str, file, [other arguments])`. I have a list containing several file paths of json files and would like to read each of them, collapsing the results into a list.

Normally, `lapply` would be ideal for this. However, in order to read from a file, the `json_str` argument cannot be given, even a null value. This is because `fromJSON` uses `missing` to check whether arguments are given. If both `file` and `json_str` are given, an error is thrown.

That means that `lapply(files, fromJSON, json_str = NULL)` will not work. I'm aware that I could work around this by manually making my own function as follows.

```
result <- lapply(files, function(file) {
  fromJSON(file = file)
})
```

However, this seems cumbersome and unnecessary. Is there some cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Unless you can set it separately with `lapply`'s `...` argument, there's really no way around it, especially if you want to indicate an argument much later in the list, like `read.table(text = ...)`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know of a cleaner way either. Depending on your view of "cleaner" though, you might give the anonymous function a name, say `fromJSONfile`, so it would just be `lapply(files, fromJSONfile)`.

Comment: You could use `fromJSON` from the package `jsonlite` instead. It have `txt` as first argument which could be a JSON string, URL or file